About countable family of sets in R satisfying a hitting condition
I was working on a problem when I hit a little snag about a geometric problem. To properly describe it, let me introduce some notions.

We say that a point $p$ hits a set $X$ if $p\in X$.
We say that a point $p$ hits a family of sets $\mathcal F$ if $p$ hits $B$ for all $B\in \mathcal F$.
We say that a family $\mathcal F$ is finitely hittable if there is a finite set of points $P$ such that for any set $B\in\mathcal F$, there is a point $p\in P$ such that $p$ hits $B$.

Now call a countable family $\mathcal F$ of sets in $\mathbb R$ good if it satisfies the following property : $\mathcal F$ is not finitely hittable implies there exists a countable subfamily of $\mathcal F$ made of disjoint sets.
I want to look at when a family is good. So far I have found the following.

If the sets in $\mathcal F$ are compact and connected, then $\mathcal F$ is good.
If the sets in $\mathcal F$ are not necessarily compact, then there is a family that is not good.
If the sets in $\mathcal F$ are compact but can have arbitrarily many number of components (even if restricted to finite but unbounded number of components), then there is a family that is not good.

What I am stuck at is proving (or finding a counterexample of) the goodness of $\mathcal F$ when all the sets in the family are compact and the number of connected components is bounded (even for at most 2 connected components).

I have tried a couple of proof ideas but none really worked. One of them that I thought would work but did not was via induction on the bound on the number of connected components.
The base case of 1 components is handled by the result of bullet point 1. Assuming it holds for at most $k$ connected components, I am looking not at families with at most $k+1$ connected components. Roughly, my idea was to look at one component from each set, use the result from the base case, get a disjoint set of components, consider the subfamily of sets from which those components belong to, throwing away those components and if they are not disjoint then induct. But the condition of not being finitely hittable may not hold for this family. So I am stuck (If it's finitely hittable, then one can look at the whole family minus this subfamily which, but then that doesn't decrease the number of components so induction doesn't help right now. If I can show this process terminates in a non-finitely hittable subfamily after finitely many iterations, then we are done, but I can't even do that).
I have tried my hand at counterexamples too but nothing really came of it. My gut feeling says it's false, but no dice really.
Any help is appreciated.

Question: In your definition of a 'good family', by 'countable' in '...there exists a countable subfamily of $F$ made of disjoint sets', is it implicitly assumed that it is an infinite countable subfamily? At least, is there some untold cardinality restriction on this subfamily? Otherwise,  a 'good family' simply means 'if the family is not finitely hittable, then it admits two disjoint members', right?

@JordanPayette I am so sorry for the late reply. Yes, I did mean countably infinite, sorry for not being clear.

Let's recall the context of the question (taking into account OP's comment to the question). Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a countable family of (for our purposes, compact) subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

$\mathcal{F}$ is finitely hittable (FH) if there exists a finite set $P \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $B \in \mathcal{F}$, $B \cap P \neq \varnothing$.

Let's introduce a new terminology: $\mathcal{F}$ is infinitary recurrent (IR) if for every infinite (countable) subset $\mathcal{F}' \subset \mathcal{F}$, there exist two $B, B' \in \mathcal{F}'$ such that $B \cap B' \neq \varnothing$.

$\mathcal{F}$ is good if either it is not IR, or it is IR and FH. In other words, 'good' = 'IR $\rightarrow$ FH'. (This definition of good is the contrapositive to OP's definition.)


Main proposition. Assume $\mathcal{F}$ consists of compact (nonempty) subsets, each having at most $n$ connected components (where $n \in \mathbb{N}$). Then $\mathcal{F}$ is good.
For notational simplicity, we shall only consider here the case $n=2$, but the argument is easily adapted to every other $n$ (the simpler case $n=1$ is already known to the OP).
Setup. Replacing the elements of $\mathcal{F}$ by their images under the homeomorphism $(2/\pi) \mathrm{tan} : \mathbb{R} \to (- 1, 1)$, we may assume that every $B \in \mathcal{F}$ is contained in $(-1, 1)$. We may also assume that every $B \in \mathcal{F}$ has two connected components, for if $\mathcal{F}_{\ast} = \{B_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathcal{F}$ denotes the (countable) collection of $B \in \mathcal{F}$ having only one connected component, then we can replace each $B_i$ by $B_i \cup \{2 + 1/i\}$, thereby obtaining a new $\mathcal{F}'$ which is still IR and $\neg$FH. (We can then use a contraction of $\mathbb{R}$ to ensure that all sets in $\mathcal{F}$ are in $(-1,1)$).
Given $B = [a,b] \cup [a',b'] \in \mathcal{F}$ (where $-1 < a \le b < a' \le b' < 1$), let $c = (a+b)/2$ and $c' = (a'+b')/2$ be the middle points of the 'intervals' $[a,b]$ and $[a', b']$. We set $C_B := \{ c, c’\}$. We define the size of $B$ as $|B| = \mathrm{max}(b-a, b'-a')$,  the length of the longest 'interval' of $B$.
It will be convenient sometimes to view an element $B = [a,b] \cup [a',b'] \in \mathcal{F}$ as a 'rectangle' $\hat{B} = [a,b] \times [a',b'] \subset [-1,1]^2$, and similarly to view $C_B = \{c, c'\}$ as the point $\hat{C}_B = (c, c') \in [-1,1]^2$. We set $\hat{F} = \{ \hat{B} \, : \, B \in \mathcal{F} \}$.
Motivational observation. Suppose there were some $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that $|B| \ge \epsilon_0$ for all $B \in \mathcal{F}$. Then considering $P = \{ -1 + i \epsilon_0/2 \, : 0 \le i \le 4/\epsilon_0\}$, we would have $B \cap P \neq \varnothing$ for every $B \in \mathcal{F}$, thereby proving that $\mathcal{F}$ is FH. So the crux of the proof is to understand how sequences $\{B_i\}_i \subset \mathcal{F}$ with $\lim_{i \to \infty} | B_i| = 0$ behave.
Accumulation pairs. So let's consider the (say, nonempty) collection $\mathcal{C} \subset [-1,1]^{\underline{2}}$ defined as follows: $C = \{c, c’\} \in \mathcal{C}$ iff there exists a sequence $\mathsf{B} = \{B_i\}_i \subset \mathcal{F}$ such that (i) $\lim_{i \to \infty} | B_i| = 0$ and (ii) $\lim_{i \to \infty} C(B_i) = C$. A shrinking sequence is a sequence $\{B_i\}_i \subset \mathcal{F}$  satisfying (i); it is converging (to $C$) if it satisfies (ii). Note that by compactness of $[-1,1]$, if there exists a shrinking sequence, then there exists a converging one. We call the elements $C \in \mathcal{C}$ the accumulation pairs for $\mathcal{F}$. (For general $n$, we would speak of accumulation $n$-ples.) We set $\hat{\mathcal{C}} := \{ \hat{C} \, : \, C \in \mathcal{C} \} \subset [-1,1]^2$.
(To be clear, we note that a shrinking sequence could consist of sets of size $0$.)
Lemma 1. The set $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (hence compact).
Proof. Consider a sequence $\{\hat{C}_i \}_i \subset \hat{\mathcal{C}}$ converging to some pair $\hat{C}_{\infty} \in [-1,1]^2$. Each $\hat{C}_i$ is itself the limit of a convergent shrinking sequence $\hat{\mathsf{B}}_i$. By a diagonal argument, it follows that there exists a shrinking sequence converging to $\hat{C}_{\infty}$, hence $\hat{C}_{\infty} \in \hat{\mathcal{C}}$. QED
Lemma 2. For every $C = \{c, c'\} \in \mathcal{C}$, there exist open sets $U \ni c$ and $U' \ni c'$ such that for all $B \in \mathcal{F}$ satisfying $B \subset W := U \cup U'$, $B$ is hit by $C$, i.e., $B \cap C \neq \varnothing$.
Proof. Suppose otherwise: there is some $C = \{c, c'\} \in \mathcal{C}$ such that for all open sets $U \ni c$ and $U' \ni c'$, there exists $B \in \mathcal{F}$ satisfying $B \subset W := U \cup U'$ and $B \cap C = \varnothing$.
We construct a sequence $\mathsf{B} \subset \mathcal{F}$ consisting of pairwise disjoint sets as follows. First, pick any $B_1 \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $B_1 \cap C = \varnothing$. By induction, suppose we have constructed for $1 \le k \le j$ pairwise disjoint sets $B_k \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $B_k \cap C = \varnothing$. By compactness of $B_1, \dots, B’’_j$ and $C$ and since the former are disjoint from the latter, there exists some open set $W_j := U_j \cup U'_j  \supset C$ such that $B_k \cap W_j = \varnothing$ for  all $1 \le k \le j$. By the above absurd assumption, there exists $B_{j+1} \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $B_{j+1} \subset U_j$ and $B_{j+1} \cap C = \varnothing$.  Hence $B_k \cap B_{j+1} = \varnothing$ for all $1 \le j \le k$.
We thus obtain an infinite collection $\mathsf{B} \subset \mathcal{F}$ consisting of pairwise disjoint sets, which contradicts $\mathcal{F}$ being IR. QED
Corollary 1. Lemma 2 has the following rephrasing: For every $\hat{C} = (c, c') \in \hat{\mathcal{C}}$, there exist open sets $\hat{W} = U \times U' \ni (c, c')$ such that for all $\hat{B} \in \hat{\mathcal{F}}$ satisfying $\hat{B} \subset \hat{W}$, $\hat{B}$ is hit by the finitely many lines $\widetilde{C} := (C \times \mathbb{R}) \cup (\mathbb{R} \times C)$, i.e., $\hat{B} \cap \widetilde{C} \neq \varnothing$.
Proof of Main proposition. If $\mathcal{C} = \varnothing$, then there exists no shrinking sequence, hence there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $|B| > \epsilon$ for all $B \in \mathcal{F}$. Hence $\mathcal{F}$ is FH, as argued in the above Motivational observation.
Let $\mathcal{C} \neq \varnothing$. By Corollary 2, for each $\hat{C} \in \hat{\mathcal{C}}$, there exists an open set $\hat{W_C} \ni \hat{C}$ such that for all $\hat{B} \in \hat{\mathcal{F}}$ satisfying $\hat{B} \subset \hat{W_C}$, we have $\hat{B} \cap \widetilde{C} \neq \varnothing$. The collection $\mathcal{W} := \{ \hat{W_C} \, : \, C \in \mathcal{C} \}$ is an open cover of $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$. By Lemma 1, $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^n$, hence there exists a finite subcover $\mathcal{W}' = \{ \hat{W_{C_i}} \}_{1 \le i \le N} \subset \mathcal{W}$ of $\hat{\mathcal{C}}$. The cover $\mathcal{W}'$ admits a positive Lebesgue number $\delta$: this means in particular that any 'rectangle' of side-lengths $< \delta':= \delta/\sqrt{n}$ is contained in some $\hat{W_{C_i}}$. So let's consider a finite partition $P_1$ of $[-1,1]$ of mesh $< \delta'$. We can thus decompose $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{F}_1 \cup \mathcal{F}_2$, where $\mathcal{F}_1$ consists of those $B$s that intersect $P_1$ and $\mathcal{F}_2$ consists of those $B$s that don't intersect $P_1$.
On the one hand, by definition, $\mathcal{F}_1$ if FH by $P_1$. On the other hand, we can split $\mathcal{F}_2$ into $\mathcal{F}_{2,1}$, consisting of those $B$s such that $\hat{B}$ is contained in $\cup \mathcal{W}'$, and $\mathcal{F}_{2,2}$, consisting of those $B$s such that $\hat{B}$ is not contained in $\cup \mathcal{W}'$.
Since each $B \in \mathcal{F}_{2,1}$ satisfies $|B| < \delta'$ and $\hat{B}$ is contained in $\cup \mathcal{W}'$, $\hat{B}$ is contained in some $\hat{W_{C_i}}$, i.e., $B$ is contained in $W_{C_i}$, hence by Lemma 1, $B \cap C_i \neq \varnothing$. Therefore, $\mathcal{F}_{2,1}$ is FH by $P_{2,1} := \cup_{1 \le i \le N} C_i$.
We claim that the collection $\mathcal{F}_{2,2}$ is FH too (by some finite set $P_{2,2}$). Assume otherwise. Then $\mathcal{F}_{2,2}$ cannot be finite. By the Motivational observation and by compactness of $[-1,1]^n$, the collection $\mathcal{F}_{2,2}$ thus contains a convergent shrinking sequence $\mathsf{B}$, necessarily converging to some $C \in \mathcal{C}$, hence there is some $B \in \mathsf{B}$ such that $\hat{B} \subset \cup \mathcal{W}'$, which is absurd.
All in all, $\mathcal{F}$ is FH by $P := P_1 \cup P_{2,1} \cup P_{2,2}$. QED
